# Transitioning from rsync to ZFS send/receive

Tags: backup, rsync, zfs, incremental-backup

I recently converted my backup server and offsite backup server to ZFS. I used to use rsync to do incremental backups to the offsite server, but now I would like to transition to using ZFS send and receive (over ssh).

The issue I have is that I don't want to send the entire data set over the internet to get the ball rolling. Since I already have the same files in both locations (kept in sync via rsync), is there a way to jump straight to sending incremental snapshots?

I suppose I could `zfs send` to an external drive and then manually bring it to the offsite location and run `zfs receive`, but that would require buying a big external drive and it seems like a waste.

Comment: From the manpage of an Ubuntu 16.04, `zfs send -i ...` will stream an incremental dataset of two snapshots. Never tested it and not sure how the `receive` way will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No options. You'll need to copy the data over again.

Comment: :( I was afraid of that. Thanks for confirming it though.